# Add allowed values list programmatically in drupal CCK field “list_text”

Tags: entities

I was wondering if i can create programmatically a CCK field instance and insert the "allowed_values" in a single stage. So i tried this:

```
 field_create_instance(array(
  'field_name' => 'card number',
  'entity_type' => 'payment_method',
  'bundle' => 'debit_card',
  'label' => t('Debit/Credit card'),
  'description' => t('Add card\'s number '),
  'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'options_select',
      'weight' => 0,
      'settings' => array('size' => 50),
   ),
  'required' => TRUE,
 ));
```

I've tried some cases i.e to set in 'settings' => array( 'allowed_values' => array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) but nothing happened. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that needs to be an array of matching key/value pairs. Try `array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3)`. You may also need this in your settings array: `'allowed_values_function' => ''`

Comment: Did that solve it? I can post as an answer below and be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Yes, i solve it! Thanks a lot! But just to know, it worked for me when i moved my "allowed_values_function" callback in .module file. So if you want to scaffold your module set your callback inside .module file.